# Why is my VS SDL 2.0 window 2x bigger than i specified?

Tags: visual-studio, window, sdl-2

I have a 3840x2160 Monitor, using Windows 10.
I am just creating a window and a renderer. When I set the window size to 200x200 and run the programm, the window shows up and I can render perfectly. But the window really is 400x400 pixels big and a point (SDL_RenderDrawPoint()) is actually 2x2 pixels big. Also when i draw the point at 10,10 it is on the position 20,20 counted by pixels. 
When I set the Windows 10 resolution in the settings to 1920x1080 the window has the right size and points are only one pixel big and on the right position.
I would be really thankful if somebody knows something about that problem and how to get the window to the pixel perfect size with the 3840x2160 settings. ;)

Comment: There are magnification settings in Windows 10.  Have you checked those?

Comment: No i did not. Setting them to 100% fixed it but now everything else is small too. Do you know a way to have the settings on maybe 200% and still have the window not sized up by 200% ? thank you btw :)

Comment: In WPF you can simply [scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-scale-an-element) things.  I have no idea how one would do that in SDL.

Comment: Try the `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` flag when creating the window.

Comment: I tried and I really thought that was my fix after looking what the flag does but it somehow did nothing for me. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you solved the issue ages ago, but in case someone still has trouble with it:
The issue is that Windows scales the window using the UI scaling setting (DPI scaling), as the program is flagged as non DPI aware.
I had the same issue with my game on Steam. There are two ways to get Windows 8+ to not apply the scaling to your game:
1)
right click on your compiled .exe
select properties
open the compatibility Tab
select Change High DPI settings
Tick the bottom box and choose:
Override High DPI scaling behavior.

Scaling performed by:
Application

This solution is inelegant and not suited for distribution, as you would need every user to do the same.

2. if using visual studio, set your manifest file to: DPI aware, monitor aware (and try to do the appropriate scaling in your program, or have options for the user to do so).
   To access the manifest, in Visual Studio 2013:
   Right Click on your target program in Solution Explorer, select: Configuration Properties\Manifest Tool
   Set DPI Awareness to: Per Monitor High DPI Aware,
   And Windows should leave your game alone.

Comment: I also do it like this now, cause its more consistent.

Comment: One of my testers reported windows flickering the screen and trying to scale the window on AI turn as the calculations made the display stutter. I need to check whether it is really an effect of display stuttering.

Comment: If you are using CMake to configure the project, try to add `set_property(TARGET <your_target_name> PROPERTY VS_DPI_AWARE "PerMonitor")` at `CMakeList.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is that my window is not DPI aware, so windows bitmap-scales it. The normal fix for that would be to give the `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` flag to the window when it is created, but sadly there is no windows support for DPI awareness yet (or I just didn't find anything about it) so it doesnt work. [Some Poeple](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/current-status-of-high-dpi-support-on-windows/22174) are working to get a windows [Per-Monitor (V2) DPI Awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for SDL2 on windows.
Anyways I just found a weird fix for the problem I decribed in the question above: 
I can just use the `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` flag ( width and height are unimportant ), to map my window to the fullscreen ignoring the scale factor windows is using, which most of the times makes my window unusable, because of the streching. Then I close the window, take the `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` flag out and run the programm again. Now the window is in the real 1:1 Pixel size, eventhogh I have a 200% scale factor in my windows settings.
I know this is an unclean and weird fix, so if anyone knows why this works or knows a better way, go ahead.